# Root Path variable in Javascript is null after Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to store Root url in a javascript variable  in my `_Layout.cshtml` as follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootpath = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        rootpath = "@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")";
    });
</script>
```

And the views as

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Sales/AddInvoice.js"></script>
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Save","Invoice",FormMethod.Post,new { @id = "frmInvoice" }))
    {
    }
```

Then in my JS file i use `rootpath` like this :

```
prepUIAutocomp(rootpath + "Sales/Invoice/GetCustomer", "clientid", "ClientMst_clientname", {}, null, 1);
```

It works fine untill postback/refresh. After which `rootpath` is `undefined`.

since each view uses `_Layout.cshtml` the path should be updated with with each request right? or am i missing something ?

i want to be able to use `rootpath` variable in all my views and their related javascripts for creating ajax related urls. Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well slow day it seams. 
I had to change my script as follow and it worked. Posting here for others who faced similar problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var rootpath = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var x = "@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")";
        if (x && x != "")
            rootpath = x;
    });
</script>
```

But my original question still stands.

Why would the value of `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/")` be null in the first place?

And what is causing the value of rootpath to disppear?